# Append item to map with Yecc parser in Elixir/Erlang

Tags: erlang, elixir, leex, yecc

I am trying parsing a specific log file with Leex/Yecc in Elixir. After many hours I got the easiest scenario to work. However I want to go to the next step, but I cannot figure out how to do so.

First, here is an example of the log format:

```
[!] plugin error detected
 |  check the version of the plugin
```

My simple try was only with the first line, but multiple entries of them, as such:

```
[!] plugin error detected
[!] plugin error 2 detected
[!] plugin error 3 detected
```

That worked and gave me a nice map containing the text and the log line type (warning):

```
iex(20)> LogParser.parse("[!] a big warning\n[!] another warning")
[%{text: "a big warning", type: :warning},
 %{text: "another warning", type: :warning}]
```

That is perfect. But as seen above a log line can continue on a next line, indicated with a pipe character `|`. My lexer has the pipe character and the parser can understand it, but what I want is the next line to be appended to the `text` value of my map. For now it is just appended as a string in the map. So instead of:

```
[%{text: "a big warning ", type: :warning}, " continues on next line"]
```

I need:

```
[%{text: "a big warning continues on next line", type: :warning}]
```

I looked at examples on the net, but most of them have really clear 'end' tokens, such as a closing tag or a closing bracket, and then still it is not really clear to me how to add properties so the eventual AST is correct.

For completeness, here is my lexer:

```
Definitions.

Char          = [a-zA-Z0-9\.\s\,\[\]]
Word          = [^\t\s\.#"=]+
Space         = [\s\t]
New_Line      = [\n]
%New_Line      = \n|\r\n|\r
Type_Regular  = \[\s\]\s
Type_Warning  = \[!\]\s
Pipe          = \|

Rules.

{Type_Regular}  : {token, {type_regular,  TokenLine}}.
{Type_Warning}  : {token, {type_warning,  TokenLine}}.
{Char}          : {token, {char, TokenLine, TokenChars}}.
{Space}         : skip_token.
{Pipe}          : {token, {pipe, TokenLine}}.
{New_Line}      : skip_token.

Erlang code.
```

And my parser:

```
Nonterminals lines line line_content chars.
Terminals type_regular type_warning char pipe.
Rootsymbol lines.

lines -> line lines : ['$1'|['$2']].
lines -> line : '$1'.

line -> pipe line_content : '$2'.
line -> type_regular line_content : #{type => regular, text => '$2'}.
line -> type_warning line_content : #{type => warning, text => '$2'}.

line_content -> chars : '$1'.
line_content -> pipe chars : '$1'.

chars -> char chars : unicode:characters_to_binary([get_value('$1')] ++ '$2').
chars -> char : unicode:characters_to_binary([get_value('$1')]).

Erlang code.

get_value({_, _, Value}) -> Value.
```

If you got even this far, **thank you** already! If anyone could help out, even bigger thanks!

Comment: I cannot test this right now, but I think you should remove `line -> pipe line_content : '$2'.` and make `line_content` handle multiple lines. In PEG like notation, that would be `line_content = chars (pipe chars)*`, i.e. chars followed by 0 or more `(pipe chars)`.

Comment: @Dogbert aha ok thanks, I tried searching on parsing multiple lines but cannot get a good example. I will search further on your proposal, thanks a bunch already!

Comment: I don't have the time to look at this in detail at the moment, but I did a lightning talk on a little project using leex/yecc (in Erlang) at Erlang/Elixir Conf in SF a few months ago. Link to the slides are here, which includes a references section at the end with links I found useful for examples: https://github.com/derek121/mrwhite

Comment: @JeroenBourgois if you could upload a compilable package for the code in the question somewhere (Github/Dropbox?), I'll try to do the modification I suggested and let you know if it works.

Comment: @Dogbert I put the project on github: https://github.com/jackjoe/wpscan-logparser

Comment: @DerekBrown thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a `line_content` rule to handle multiple lines separated by pipes and removing the rule `line -> pipe line_content : '$2'.`.

You also have an unnecessary `[]` around `'$2'` in the `lines` clause and the single line clause should return a list to be consistent with the return value of the previous clause and so you don't end up with improper lists.

With these four changes,

```
-lines -> line lines : ['$1'|['$2']].
+lines -> line lines : ['$1'|'$2'].
-lines -> line : '$1'.
+lines -> line : ['$1'].

-line -> pipe line_content : '$2'.
 line -> type_regular line_content : #{type => regular, text => '$2'}.
 line -> type_warning line_content : #{type => warning, text => '$2'}.

 line_content -> chars : '$1'.
-line_content -> pipe chars : '$1'.
+line_content -> line_content pipe chars : <<'$1'/binary, '$3'/binary>>.
```

I can parse multiline text just fine:

```
Belino.parse("[!] Look at the error")
Belino.parse("[!] plugin error detected
 | check the version of the plugin")
Belino.parse("[!] a
 | warning
 [ ] a
 | regular
 [ ] another
 | regular
 [!] and another
 | warning")
```

Output:

```
[%{text: "Look at the error", type: :warning}]
[%{text: "plugin error detected  check the version of the plugin",
   type: :warning}]
[%{text: "a  warning ", type: :warning}, %{text: "a  regular ", type: :regular},
 %{text: "another  regular ", type: :regular},
 %{text: "and another  warning", type: :warning}]
```

Comment: thanks man! Regarding the extra `[]`, you can see in the output now the last item has a `|` before it (in the `iex` output), so there is something wrong with the list. While looping over it with `Enum` I got an error. That is why I went back and add the brackets, since that should be the Erlang code to construct maps, either with `[1, 2]` or with `[1|[2]]`? I will test again with your edits. Also instead of actual new lines, I used `\n` but that should not matter, right?  Again, thank you SO much already!

Comment: Ah right. You should be returning a list from the second clause of `lines` as well. I've edited my answer.

Comment: it worked! Awesome. I will spend some time trying to grasp what is really going on, but I think I get it. Onto the next step: parsing the content of each line further into nested nodes, since a line itself can be parsed into a kind of map (the log has entries like date: today, importance: urgent, and so on :) Thank you again! Maybe I will post a new question later on.

Comment: as a small extra question: would you suggest testing both the lexer and the parser, or would the parser suffise? It feels not so DRY to test both, since what the lib is interested in is that a certain input matches a certain output, the in betweens are not that relevant?

Comment: I'd write tests for both. The lexer tests should just be a few lines, but could be very helpful if you modify the lexer in such a way that it only creates a parse error. Having tests for the lexer will help you catch these mistakes faster.

Comment: sorry to bother you again... but a very generic question: would you try the lexer to tokenize characters or words? The main examples I meet do both (the html parser blogpost sends characters to the parser, while for example the Toml elixir parser sends words. But when I use words I seem to have colliding rules, where the 'words' rules take precedence over more specific tokens I want to scan. Or should that be the concern of the parser? For example, if there is a set of tokens like: 'Date Created: somedate' I would like to send 2 tokens to the parser, a 'date_created_prop' followed by a 'date'.